# large value of AsyncPostBackTimeout causes Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I use UpdatePanel with large async timeout value:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  AsyncPostBackTimeout="3600000" />   
<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Block" runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RunButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It throws 'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException.' instantly.
Setting it to smaller value ie. 1200000 fixes it but why?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is a property that is set either on the site itself in the web.config or the application pool in IIS. It could be conflicting with that value? My other guess would be since the value is stored in seconds, .NET converts to milliseconds and it overflows the limit of `Int32`

Comment: Also I think that value is in seconds, so you're saying that 3,600,000 seconds is when an async postback should time out, that's over 24 hours........ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbacktimeout.aspx